# How do I get the last 2 characters of a string and turn it into an int?

Tags: java

I'm 14 so we're learning about scientific equations and ions in school.
Keep in mind I am very new to java and got the map thing from googling. I am also new to scientific equations hehe, so if you see anything please point it out (Although that is not part of the main question). I need practice in both areas so why not create a java program about science? ;) Anyway, I've got to the stage where I need to get the last 2 items in the String and change them to an integer and then I think I need to do algebra in java to solve a little equation for getting the little number infront of the letters. That's all I need to do then I can carry on making my program :D. Any help is very much appreciated and if you see anything else please point it out. Thanks!

This is the file: `Run.java`

```
package scientificFormula;

public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Formula formula = new Formula();

        formula.compound1 = args[0];
        formula.compound2 = args[1];

        String theFormula = formula.createFormula();
        System.out.println("Compound: " + args[0] + " " + args[1]
                + " = " + theFormula);
    }

}
```

and `Formula.java`:

```
package scientificFormula;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Formula {
    String compound1;
    String compound2;
    static private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    void initiateIons() {
        //1+
        map.put("Hydrogen", "H^1+");
        map.put("Lithium", "Li^1+");
        map.put("Sodium", "Na^1+");
        map.put("Potassium", "K^1+");
        map.put("Rubidium", "Rb^1+");
        //2+
        map.put("Magnesium", "Mg^2+");
        map.put("Calcium", "Ca^2+");
        map.put("Strontium", "Sr^2+");
        //3+
        map.put("Aluminium", "Al^3+");
        //3-
        map.put("Nitrogem", "N^-3");
        map.put("Phosphorus", "P^-3");
        //2-
        map.put("Oxygen", "O^-2");
        map.put("Sulfar", "S^-2");
        map.put("Selenium", "Se^-2");
        //1-
        map.put("Fluorine", "F^-1");
        map.put("Chlorine", "Cl^-1");
        map.put("Bromine", "Br^-1");
        map.put("Iodine", "I^-1");
    }

    String createFormula() {
        initiateIons();

        //Example Calcium Iodine:
        //2x + -1y = 0
        //x = 1 and y = 2

        String symbol1 = map.get(compound1);
        String symbol2 = map.get(compound2);

        return symbol1 + symbol2;
    }
}
```

**edit**:

In reply to the 2 comments below from Jigar and Eran:
I went in properties and changed the arguments on `Run.java`...
input:

```
Sodium Chlorine
```

output:

```
Compound: Sodium Chlorine = Na^1+Cl^1-
```

for example this string: "Iodine", "I^-1"
and the 2 items are -1 I want to make that int. Thanks.

Comment: you can clarify on input and output

Comment: `I need to get the last 2 items in the String and change them to an integer` - What 2 items and in what String?

Comment: Note that you can use [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to split the string at the `^` character.  This will allow you to have a variable number of characters after the `^` and still access them.

Comment: Ok I'll google the split method and see how it works. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want the last two **characters** of the string not bits. If I'm not mistaken you want to grab the `-2` at the end of something like Oxygen.

This can be done with these lines of code:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(str.replace("+", "").substring(str.length() - 2));
```

The replace is necessary because parseInt does not like `+` in front of values only `-`.

Using Hot Licks suggestion of `split` you can do something like:

```
String[] symbol1Parts = symbol1.split("\\^");
int symbol1Int = Integer.parseInt(symbol1Parts[1].replace("+", "")); // the [1] assumes that there will only be one ^ character before the charge
String[] symbol2Parts = symbol2.split("\\^");
int symbol2Int = Integer.parseInt(symbol2Parts[1].replace("+", "")); // the [1] assumes that there will only be one ^ character before the charge
```

Comment: I changed it to:`int charge1 = Integer.parseInt(symbol1.replace("+", "").substring(symbol1.length() - 2));`
`int charge2 = Integer.parseInt(symbol2.replace("+", "").substring(symbol2.length() - 2));`
  
`return charge1 + charge2;` and it says: Description Resource Path Location Type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String Formula.java /Scientifc Forumla/src/scientificFormula line 50 Java Problem

Comment: @gogobebe2 Did you change your return type? Also I would look at `split` method though as Hot Licks suggested in case we ever discover an ion with a charge of `+10`.

Comment: Oh haha forgot about the method type. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: I've now changed it using the split methond:

  String[] parts1 = symbol1.split("^");
  String sym1 = parts1[0];
  String num1 = parts1[1];
  
  String[] parts2 = symbol2.split("^");
  String sym2 = parts2[0];
  String num2 = parts2[1];
  
  int charge1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.replace("+", "").substring(num1.length() - 2));
  int charge2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.replace("+", "").substring(num2.length() - 2));
  
  return sym1 + charge1 + sym2 + charge2;
 } But it gives an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: Sorry about bad indenting. This commenting system doesn't let you use new lines. :/

Comment: Yes it appears that the `split` method does not like `"^"` because it wants to match regex (`^` is a special operator in regex). Instead put `"\\^"`. On top of that you no longer need the `substring` calls because the `split` should take care of that. Also just FYI the return statement is performing concatenation not addition.

Comment: Finally a large part of programming is not only writing code but debugging it. It is as important to know why your code **doesn't** do something as why it **does** do something. Use the wonderful java API to guide you on your way as well as you best friend [google](http://www.google.com).

Comment: Thankyou so much. It really is apprieciated. I'm still learning java and half way through the tutorial don't know too much so just doing this for a fun extra. I'll try hard to understand what this is doing. And thanks again for taking time out of your life to help me.